# Активные PHP скрипты

Tags: php

Есть проблема: на сервере постоянно переписывается один файл. Нужно понять каким скриптом это делается. Поиск по файлам не совсем вариант, ибо этот путь может быть в десятках скриптов. Скрипт точно запускается по хитам и таких запусков десятки. Нужно знать какой скрипт работает в конкретный момент времени.

Comment: установить изменяемому файлу запрет на запись и посмотреть, какой скрипт выбросит эксепшн

Comment: @DmitryKozlov а что если выброс эксепшена не предусмотрен или ловится?

Comment: тогда поиск по сорцам

Comment: @DmitryKozlov выброс исключения не возможен. Ибо это продакшен сервер. Куча студий работало с проектом и вот такие вот сюрпризы приходится вылавливать.

Comment: И что самое печальное - поиск по пути файла ничего не дал.

Comment: Возможно вот это вам поможет, сам не пробовал: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.fam-monitor-file.php

Comment: @DmitryKozlov спасибо! Попробую. Сам не находил этой функции.

Comment: Можно попробовать приблизить решение используя например fswatch https://www.ostechnix.com/monitor-file-changes-using-fswatch-linux/  если файл меняется в ответ на какие то действия, методом перебора действий может быть получится поймать момент и понять что именно запускается после действия.